# How to make a Group by in OCL?

Tags: ocl

I have an association between **Person** and **Department**, and I want to check if Person.function is unique

```
Person.allInstances->isUnique(function)
```

but I want to check if function is unique for Persons in the same department and not between all persons. I can have the same function but not in the same department.
I don't know how to use isUnique for each department (**Persons group by department**).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scope for which isUnique is to apply then gather that scope as the source. Perhaps as department.persons->isUnique(function). (This is exactly the approach that you should apply anyway to avoid using the generally over-powerful and inefficient allInstances() wherever possible.)